# Can we define a smooth curve through maximums?!

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq0}$ be a smooth map, $S_t(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ denote the sphere of radius $t$ centered at the origin. Let $m_f(t)=\max_{x\in S_t(0)} f(x)$ and $X_f(t)=\{x\in S_t(0): f(x)=m_f(t) \}$. Can we choose a $\gamma(t) \in X_f(t)$ for all $t>0$, so that $\gamma(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth (maybe not connected) curve?

Comment: What structure of differential manifold do you impose on the product $\mathbf{R}^{\geq 0}$? Or what do you mean by that symbol.

Comment: $R^{\geq 0}$ is the set of non-negative real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible in general, and I think a counterexample looks like this:

Start with $f(x,y)=x^2$.

Our curve would have to pass through either $(-1,0)$ or $(1,0)$.

Now take a smooth function $g$ that:

- is zero outside an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $(1,0)$
- is bounded in absolute value by $\epsilon$

  - changes signs infinitely often near $(1,0)$

Then try to construct such a curve for $f + g$.

The maxima on the circles of radius close to 1 should bounce back and forth between the positive and negative sides of the graph infinitely often, making it impossible to draw such a curve.

(You'll have to check the details yourself as I'm writing this on my phone.)